Non agency (R/C)MBS & ABS pricing available tools & instructions
What tools and instructions can I use to model non agency MBS/ABS products, I would like to be able to price those securities, and compare my result against data vendors (markit, Reuters, etc). Ideally in python but any other options are welcome.
Also I can use a Bloomberg terminal, but I don't know how to model cashflows there.
Are there any useful tools with instructions?
